# Efficient bike parking/storage that younger kids can handle?

Tags: storage

We have a smallish 2-car garage on our house, which with both cars in it, is difficult to put all 6 of our family's bikes in as well.  My bike is typically hung from some hooks in the ceiling, and I have a hoist on the ceiling for my wife's bike.  However, I have not found an effective way to get all the kids' bikes in.  I have tried hooks such as these:

[image] [image]

which lets them fit, but I find that the bikes fall out of them quite easily unless the bike is lifted all the way off the ground, which the kids lack the ability to do.  I thought of putting in more hoists, except that there is not enough ceiling room left to do so (without coming down on a car, that is) and I'm concerned with the kids securing them wrong and having one fall (damaging the bike, the kid or a car).

Does anyone have an innovative way to store multiple bikes in a tight space that does not require significant lifting?  The kids are able to get the bikes up on a rear wheel, but not typically to lift it enough to get it in a hook that would keep it off the ground.

Comment: How old are these kids? If they're small that they're only riding with parent supervision, can a parent just put the bikes up on the hooks? Or are you hoping to make it so they can learn to put them away themselves?

Comment: They are 4, 8, 12 and 14.  The 4 year old obviously doesn't need to put her bike away on her own yet (12" bikes are easy to stick in a corner anyway), but I was hoping the others could get their bikes in and out on their own.  The 14 yr old is getting big enough that he can probably get his all the way off the floor, but it would do little good without the other bikes out of the way.

Comment: Do they need to be off the ground? If they can't lift them, I don't think theres a way around it. But you could use a floor based stand like http://weartested.org/zictech-ultimate-bike-stand (haven't tried this particular one, but one of the local bike shops has a similar thing for bike parking) if they don't have to be off the ground.

Comment: I suppose you could replace the hook with a pulley, and attach a rope with a carabiner to one end. The biner would have the same function as a hook, just more secure. With sufficient advantage in the pulley system even a 5 year old should be able to clear the ground. Quick tip, if you can't eye splice the line, I would suggest you attach the biner using at least a bowline knot (if you don't know what one is, then you need to learn THIS knot rather than any knots you do know).

Comment: @Batman They don't need to be off the ground. It's just that when I tried using hooks to store them vertically, I found that if the back tire was still on the ground then the bikes were very likely to fall out of the hooks when bumped.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your garage arragement, I would consider sth like this, but for vertical position:
[image]
mixed with hoist:
[image]

with this kind of elevating mechanism:

[image]

If for horizontal, can be combined with this ( I suppose there is enoug space on the wall if you tried with hooks):

[image]

Comment: Your first pic is what I currently have for my wife's bike.  I'm not sure what you're envisioning when you say using that hoist in "vertical position".  The hand winch is something I had not thought of, but it's opening up more ideas to me now.

Comment: @techturtle Added my vision  with "stabilization rails".

Answer (score 1):

there is a plywood version of a bike corral that has the hooks and corresponding "wheel slots" at a forty five degree angle (or more) to the wall, allowing efficient storage.

with the front wheel hooked inside the hook on the wall, and the rear wheel in the "wheel slot" on the ground, you can hook the front wheel up on the wall, and the rear wheel in the slot will keep it from flopping.

it sort of looks like the vertical storage racks on this website: http://www.dero.com/design-guides/bike-rooms/

i would just design a rack out of 2x4s and put hooks at corresponding wheelbase lengths for your children to use.  without having to lift, they'll be able to hook their bikes up and down easily.

the only problem with this design is having the necessary woodworking abilities to keep it cost effective.